# Adobe Acrobat DC dynamic stamps multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, dynamic, adobe

Does anyone have experience with javascript in Adobe Acrobat DC?

I am trying and making dynamic stamps, and with the help of various guides and tutorials, I can solve what I want with one input field.

It looks like this:

```
var cAsk = "Anvises til udbetaling";
var cTitle = "ATU"

if(event.source.forReal &&
    (event.source.stampName == "#stamp1"))
{
     event.value = app.response(cAsk, cTitle);  
}
```

The above provoke a javascript popup with an input field that you can type in, and it will appear on the stamp.

My problem is for multiple input fields, so I would like all inputs to be filled in in the same popup, instead of each input having its own popup as is the case with the javascript inserted in pastebin.

It's easier annoying when you have seven fields to fill in, then you meet seven popups followed by each other. instead of just being able to fill in the seven fields in the same popup :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the app.execDialog function.  You can have multiple text fields, check boxes, radio buttons, dropdowns, listboxes, etc.  It's not easy but you can read about it [here](https://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/9/Acrobat9_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?href=JS_API_AcroJS.88.1.html#1515776&accessible=true).

Type 'execDialog' in the search field.